# Android Studio Translation Editor disable auto refresh

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way to disable auto update/refresh in Android Studio 2.3.1 Translations Editor?

After editing one field, the editor automatically refreshes and goes back to default layout and string list order. Is there a way to disable to behaviour?

Comment: Wondering myself. This makes translating strings very frustrating.

Comment: seems to be disabled now in AS 3, and now I need it as I add the strings manually to the XML but check which ones I need using the Translations Editor